# Only display complete items in a stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a slider which consists of grid of:

- Scrollviewer
- Stackpanel (the stackpanel is located inside the viewer)

The slider has 2 navigation buttons to browse trough the selected items.

But how can i only show complete items? Currently some buttons only get shown in half because there is no more space available. In the final version only 5 buttons should be shown at once. But if a certain event is fired more buttons will be visible for.

*For example 1-5 are visible. If another button pops up only 2-6 should be visible.*

The buttons inside the slider have to be created dynamically.
Does it make sense to stick with stack panel? Cause at the moment the buttons are static.

**EDIT:**  When adding buttons dynamicly to the stackpanel how exactly does this work for already custom made buttons? I can add a normal button just fine but i wish to add the buttons already made below.

[image]

Comment: Doubt this helps here but I have noticed in a ComboBox or ListBox if it only displays a TextBlock then it keeps it whole.  But a more complex control like a button will get cut.

Comment: Can you add some code to show how they're being generated in the first place?  XAML databinding code would help also.

Comment: Currently the buttons are not being generated dynamically yet. But the problem is i am not really sure what control to take for this sort of approach. In what sort of control should the 5 buttons be displayed?

Comment: You could cheat and manually set the width of the stackpanel.  SizeOfButton * 5... You would have to listen for window resize events.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `VirtualizingStackPanel` (with virtualisation turned on as it is by default) can only perform item-based scrolling (as opposed to pixel-based scrolling). It might be worth trying swapping the `StackPanel` for a `VirtualizingStackPanel` to see if that fixes your problem.